# How can have extra column from each table with union query in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have two tables which look like this:

```
T1:  T1ID  |  Date  |  Time  | Barcode 
T2:  T2ID  |  Date  |  Time  | Barcode
```

I basically want to reconcile each record and return `T1ID` and `T2ID` so that I know that `T1` entry match with `T2ID`.

Result should be like this:

```
T1ID | T2ID  | Date  | Time  | Barcode
```

I have done the reconcile bit but I don't have any idea abt how do I get `T1ID` and `T2ID` in row.

Reconcile Query is below.

```
SELECT Date,Time,Barcode
FROM
  ( Select Date  ,Time  ,Barcode  from T1 
    union All 
    Select Date, Time , Barcode from T2 ) as Reconcile 

GROUP BY Date  ,Time  ,Barcode 

Having count(Date) > 1 ;
```

Can anyone point me on the right track?

Comment: Why not just select the IDs inside your union?

Comment: when i select ids in union query then it only returns the Ids from T1 table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you are looking for a "UNION ALL". It looks more like a JOIN to me.

- If you only need the records exist in BOTH tables, use INNER JOIN (or just JOIN)
- If you need any record which exists in EITHER tables, use "CROSS OUTER JOIN"
- If you need one of the tables to be "primary table", use "LEFT" or "RIGHT" OUTER JOIN

Something like this:

```
SELECT T1ID, T2ID, T1.DATE, T1.DATE, T1.BARCODE
FROM
T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.DATE = T2.DATE AND T1.TIME = T2.TIME AND T1.BARCODE = T2.BARCODE
```

Comment: Thanks.. i think i got confused here and working on the complicated solution rather then simple joins...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either as a join or as a grouped union - here's the latter:

```
SELECT max(T1ID) T1ID, max(T2ID) T2ID, Date, Time, Barcode
FROM
  ( Select T1ID, NULL T2ID, Date, Time, Barcode  from T1 
    union All 
    Select NULL T1ID, T2ID, Date, Time, Barcode from T2 ) as Reconcile 
GROUP BY Date  ,Time  ,Barcode 
Having count(Date) > 1 ;
```